# Validation on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The span's innerHTML  change depends on AJAX. If the span's innerHTML is `<img src="images/not-available.png">`, then submit should return false.

HTML:

```
<form  onsubmit="return validateemail()">
<span id= "message"><img src="images/not-available.png"></span>
<button id='submit' name="submit" type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validateemail()
{
      var munx = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;

      var muny = '<img src="images/not-available.png">';
      if (munx == muny)
      {
      alert ("Email id is already Exist");
      return false;
      }
}
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you should return false if for a validation issue and return true if validation is correct. The form will get submitted if you return true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery Validation Plugin** (http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) in your project. This is standard form validation that you can use in diffrent way.

for example:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' refers to the form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
      var message = errors == 1
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
      $("div.error span").html(message);
      $("div.error").show();
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

example of **ajax**: Submits the form via Ajax when valid.

```
$(".selector").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You are validating it wrong.

see this:

```
 <span id= "message"><img src="images/not-available.png"></span>
```

and now see this:

```
 var muny = '<img src="images/not-available.png"/>';
```

can you notice the extra "/" character in second one i.e just before img closing bracket. Thats causing the problem.

So replace with this one:

```
var muny = '<img src="images/not-available.png">';
```

Comment: @user3419304 just tested your code on jsfiddle and its working for me. get the link here: http://jsfiddle.net/6pU4n/1/